# HMVC Api request gives 404

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have a ci3 and react js project, my app is in var/www/html/reactframework directory and i have configured my virtual 
host and .htaccess like this

```
> <VirtualHost *:8081>
>         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>         ServerName local.reactframework.com
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/reactframework
>         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.reactframework.log
>         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.reactframework.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess in root

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1?vardump&thex=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [R=301,L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in user app

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

#php_value session.cookie_httponly 1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have been trying make it work for a while now but i'm not able to access my apis.
my project structure is something like this

```
reactframework
...user
....application
......modules
.......auth
.........controllers
...........Auth.js
....htacces
```

This same project is live and is working properly on aws , i'm new and have been trying to configure it for my system. I'm sure it's something very small that i'm not able to find. Please Help !!!

Comment: And yes i have added AllowOveride All in my main apache conf

Comment: check your apache error.log?